# How to configuration multiple actions using wildcard

Tags: struts2

It is possible to map multiple actions url in a single action configuration with wildcard ? I can able to do like `*/*` `*/*/*` in action names. But I don't know exactly how many nested path will come.

Since all my urls load render CommonLayout. So, I don't want to add multiple entries.

What I am doing now

```xml
<package name="myapp" extends="default" namespace="/">
    <global-results>
        <result type="tiles">CommonLayout</result>
    </global-results>
    <action name="a" />
    <action name="a/create" />
    <action name="b" />
    <action name="b/customize" />
    <action name="b/customize/app" />
    <action name="d/create" />
    <action name="d/view" />
    <action name="d/view/list" />
</package>
```

Below is the configuration which I want to have, But It is not working for all nested actions.

```xml
<package name="myapp" extends="default" namespace="/">
    <global-results>
        <result type="tiles">CommonLayout</result>
    </global-results>
    <action name="*" />
</package>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Does it work? It depends on the default action mapper logic, but you can change a mapper in configuration.

Comment: @AleksandrM : My previous question related to tiles. How you relate this question with previous one. Here my question is related to action mapping.

Comment: @RomanC If I configure like this `<action name="*" />`, it is not working nested actions like "a/b/c". So, my question is how to map all nested actions  in a package that will render CommonLayout.